# Sending an E-mail using python works only in shell

Tags: python, shell

I don't really know is this code giving me an error only when I try to run the script but works when I execute it from a shell.

testingmail.py

```
import smtplib
DEBUG = TRUE
to = 'receiver@hotmail.com'

subject = 'Sending an E-mail using python'
text = 'here is the message'

sender = 'someone@gmail.com'
password = 'password'



body = '\r\n'.join([
'To: %s' % to,
'From: %s' % sender,
'Subject: %s' % subject,
'',
text
])
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.login(sender, password)
    server.sendmail(sender, [to], body)

    print('E-mail Sent!')

except:
    print('Error sending E-mail')
```

The error is: smtplib has no attribute SMTP.
All the results I found states that it is sth wrong with the filename interfering with the email module in python, but yet nothing happens

Comment: How are you running it when it doen't work then?

Comment: How do you run it via shell?

Comment: I tried to run through the python shell and it works, but when I decided to copy the script into a file and run it through `python testingmail.py`.
It shows an error @Grimmy

Comment: @SamChats I rewrite it there

Comment: Do you have a script called `smtplib.py` in the same directory as `testingmail.py` perhaps?

Comment: @AlyHassan Do you have a file named `smtplib` in the same folder?

Comment: @cdarke I made sure not to do so, I have a file named email.py but why does it conflict with the module when I didnt call it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is making sure not to add any file named like a module in the same folder or directory in my example `email.py`

Thanks for your support